I need solution for overlapping item image on top of another?
I'm trying to make a streaming service website as practice, but the problem is when I put images, titles and episode lists in a way like columns and rows. For the image on top over I, tried changing the margin or other things but it didn't work.
I tried to change the margin, and perhaps put a container on it but it didn't work, I want it to be like this:
existing streaming service
It ended up lining up. Likes this:
My Streaming Service
I want to line up at least four columns containing a poster, title and episode. At first, the row is ok but the second and further overlaps on top of the first. This is the code:
.column {
  background-color: rgb(249, 215, 142);
  float: left;
  width: 200px;
  padding: 20px;
  height: 200px;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
}

.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: grid;
  clear: both;
  
}

<div class="row">

  <div class="column">
    <img src="/Users/sebastianpendragon/Desktop/Software Engineer Project/Image Source/Oshi No Ko Season 2.jpg" 
    style="width:200px;height:270px; margin-bottom:10px; margin-right: 15px; border:none;">
<p class="video-title">Oshi No Ko Season 2</p>
<p class="video-episode">Episode 1</p>
<p class="video-title">Sub</p>
</img>
</div>

<div class="column">
  <img src="/Users/sebastianpendragon/Desktop/Software Engineer Project/Image Source/Failure Frame Season 1.jpg" 
  alt="Failure Frame Season 1" style="width:210px;height:270px; margin-bottom:10px; margin-right: 15px">
</img>
  <p class="video-title">Failure Frame</p>
<p class="video-episode">Season 1 Episode 1</p>
<p class="video-title">Sub</p>

</div>

<div class="column">
  <img src="/Users/sebastianpendragon/Desktop/Software Engineer Project/Image Source/Vanguard Divinez Season 2.jpg" 
  alt="Vanguard Divinez Season 2" style="width:210px;height:270px; margin-bottom:10px; margin-right: 15px">
</img>
  <p class="video-title">Vanguard Divinez Season 2</p>
<p class="video-episode">Episode 1</p>
<p class="video-title">Sub</p>

  </div>

  <div class="column">
    <img src="/Users/sebastianpendragon/Desktop/Software Engineer Project/Image Source/Alya Sometimes Hides Her Feelings in Russian Season 1.jpg" 
    alt="Alya Sometimes Hides Her Feelings in Russian Season 1" style="width:210px;height:270px; margin-bottom:10px; margin-right: 15px">
    <p class="video-title">Alya Sometimes Hides Her Feelings in Russian Season 1</p>
  <p class="video-episode">Episode 1</p>
  <p class="video-title"> Dub|Sub</p>
  </img>
    </div>

    <div class="column">
      <img src="/Users/sebastianpendragon/Desktop/Software Engineer Project/Image Source/7th Time Loop The Villainess Enjoys a Carefree Life Married to Her Worst Enemy.jpg" 
      alt="7th Time Loop The Villainess Enjoys a Carefree Life Married to Her Worst Enemy Season 1" style="width:210px;height:270px; margin-bottom:10px; margin-right: 15px">
      <p class="video-title">7th Time Loop The Villainess Enjoys a Carefree Life Married to Her Worst Enemy Season 1</p>
    <p class="video-episode">Episode 1</p>
    <p class="video-title">Sub</p>
    </img>
      </div>
 
      <div class="column">
        <img src="/Users/sebastianpendragon/Desktop/Software Engineer Project/Image Source/As A Reincarnated Aristocrat I'll Use My Appraisal Skill to Rise in The World.jpg" 
        alt="As A Reincarnated Aristocrat I'll Use My Appraisal Skill to Rise in The World Season 1" style="width:210px;height:270px; margin-bottom:10px; margin-right: 15px">
        <p class="video-title">As A Reincarnated Aristocrat I'll Use My Appraisal Skill to Rise in The World Season 1</p>
      <p class="video-episode">Episode 1</p>
      <p class="video-title"> Dub|Sub</p>
      </img>
        </div>

        <div class="column">
          <img src="/Users/sebastianpendragon/Desktop/Software Engineer Project/Image Source/Chillin' in Another World with Level 2 Cheats.jpg" 
          alt="Chillin' in Another World with Level 2 Cheats Season 1" style="width:210px;height:270px; margin-bottom:10px; margin-right: 15px">
          <p class="video-title">Chillin' in Another World with Level 2 Cheats Season 1</p>
        <p class="video-episode">Episode 1</p>
        <p class="video-title"> Dub|Sub</p>
        </img>
          </div>

          <div class="column">
            <img src="/Users/sebastianpendragon/Desktop/Software Engineer Project/Image Source/Fairy Tail 100 Years Quest.jpg" 
            alt="Fairy Tail 100 Years Quest Season 1" style="width:210px;height:270px; margin-bottom:10px; margin-right: 15px">
            <p class="video-title">Fairy Tail 100 Years Quest Season 1</p>
          <p class="video-episode">Episode 1</p>
          <p class="video-title"> Dub|Sub</p>
          </img>
            </div>

            <div class="column">
              <img src="/Users/sebastianpendragon/Desktop/Software Engineer Project/Image Source/I Parry Everything.jpg" 
              alt="I Parry Everything Season 1" style="width:210px;height:270px; margin-bottom:10px; margin-right: 15px">
              <p class="video-title">I Parry Everything Season 1</p>
            <p class="video-episode">Episode 1</p>
            <p class="video-title"> Dub|Sub</p>
            </img>
              </div>

</div>

Anyone know how to fix it.

don't use float - that just makes positioning a lottery

you can solve the problem using flexbox

There are several problems with the code which I suggest you might like to mend first. There is a mixture of fixed-dimension styling, float and grid, an incorrect closing of img elements and an attempt to build into the HTML structure the row setup. I suggest stripping that out and reading up about CSS grid (possibly also introducing media queries to cope with narrow devices), definitely drop using float and consider removing inline styling, putting what is needed into the stylesheet.

Use a responsive grid, adjusting the 10em value lower for smaller tiles and higher for larger tiles.
.d1 {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(10em, 1fr));
}



body {
  margin: 1em;
}

.d1 {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(10em, 1fr));
  gap: 1em;
}

.d1 > div {
  background-color: rgb(249, 215, 142);
}

.d1 img {
  width: 100%;
  aspect-ratio: 3/4;
  object-fit: cover;
}
<div class="d1">

<div>
<img src="https://picsum.photos/250/370">
<p class="video-title">Oshi No Ko Season 2</p>
<p class="video-episode">Episode 1</p>
<p class="video-title">Sub</p>
</div>

<div>
<img src="https://picsum.photos/251/370">
<p class="video-title">Failure Frame</p>
<p class="video-episode">Season 1 Episode 1</p>
<p class="video-title">Sub</p>
</div>

<div>
<img src="https://picsum.photos/252/370">
<p class="video-title">Vanguard Divinez Season 2</p>
<p class="video-episode">Episode 1</p>
<p class="video-title">Sub</p>
</div>

<div>
<img src="https://picsum.photos/253/370">
<p class="video-title">Alya Sometimes Hides Her Feelings in Russian Season 1</p>
<p class="video-episode">Episode 1</p>
<p class="video-title"> Dub|Sub</p>
</div>

<div>
<img src="https://picsum.photos/254/370">
<p class="video-title">7th Time Loop The Villainess Enjoys a Carefree Life Married to Her Worst Enemy Season 1</p>
<p class="video-episode">Episode 1</p>
<p class="video-title">Sub</p>
</div>

<div>
<img src="https://picsum.photos/255/370">
<p class="video-title">As A Reincarnated Aristocrat I'll Use My Appraisal Skill to Rise in The World Season 1</p>
<p class="video-episode">Episode 1</p>
<p class="video-title"> Dub|Sub</p>
</div>

<div>
<img src="https://picsum.photos/256/370">
<p class="video-title">Chillin' in Another World with Level 2 Cheats Season 1</p>
<p class="video-episode">Episode 1</p>
<p class="video-title"> Dub|Sub</p>
</div>

<div>
<img src="https://picsum.photos/257/370">
<p class="video-title">Fairy Tail 100 Years Quest Season 1</p>
<p class="video-episode">Episode 1</p>
<p class="video-title"> Dub|Sub</p>
</div>

<div>
<img src="https://picsum.photos/258/370">
<p class="video-title">I Parry Everything Season 1</p>
<p class="video-episode">Episode 1</p>
<p class="video-title"> Dub|Sub</p>
</div>

</div>




try to use flex.
This will make the site more responsive.
And be more careful when closing tags. in your case <img >
An example of the use of flex:
HTML
<div class="movie">
  <img src="/Users/sebastianpendragon/Desktop/Software Engineer Project/Image Source/Oshi No Ko Season 2.jpg"/> 
  <p class="video-title">Oshi No Ko Season 2</p>
  <p class="video-episode">Episode 1</p>
  <p class="video-title">Sub</p>
</div>

<div class="movie">
  <img src="/Users/sebastianpendragon/Desktop/Software Engineer Project/Image Source/Failure Frame Season 1.jpg" 
    alt="Failure Frame Season 1"/>
  <p class="video-title">Failure Frame</p>
  <p class="video-episode">Season 1 Episode 1</p>
  <p class="video-title">Sub</p>
</div>

<div class="movie">
  <img src="/Users/sebastianpendragon/Desktop/Software Engineer Project/Image Source/Vanguard Divinez Season 2.jpg" 
  alt="Vanguard Divinez Season 2"/>
  <p class="video-title">Vanguard Divinez Season 2</p>
  <p class="video-episode">Episode 1</p>
  <p class="video-title">Sub</p>
</div>

<div class="movie">
  <img src="/Users/sebastianpendragon/Desktop/Software Engineer Project/Image Source/Alya Sometimes Hides Her Feelings in Russian Season 1.jpg" 
    alt="Alya Sometimes Hides Her Feelings in Russian Season 1"/>
  <p class="video-title">Alya Sometimes Hides Her Feelings in Russian Season 1</p>
  <p class="video-episode">Episode 1</p>
  <p class="video-title"> Dub|Sub</p>
</div>

<div class="movie">
  <img src="/Users/sebastianpendragon/Desktop/Software Engineer Project/Image Source/7th Time Loop The Villainess Enjoys a Carefree Life Married to Her Worst Enemy.jpg" 
  alt="7th Time Loop The Villainess Enjoys a Carefree Life Married to Her Worst Enemy Season 1"/>
  <p class="video-title">7th Time Loop The Villainess Enjoys a Carefree Life Married to Her Worst Enemy Season 1</p>
  <p class="video-episode">Episode 1</p>
  <p class="video-title">Sub</p>
</div>

<div class="movie">
  <img src="/Users/sebastianpendragon/Desktop/Software Engineer Project/Image Source/As A Reincarnated Aristocrat I'll Use My Appraisal Skill to Rise in The World.jpg" 
    alt="As A Reincarnated Aristocrat I'll Use My Appraisal Skill to Rise in The World Season 1" />
  <p class="video-title">As A Reincarnated Aristocrat I'll Use My Appraisal Skill to Rise in The World Season 1</p>
  <p class="video-episode">Episode 1</p>
  <p class="video-title"> Dub|Sub</p>
</div>

CSS
.main {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}

.movie {
  width: 300px;
  margin: 1rem;
  background-color: rgb(249, 215, 142);
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

img {
    width: 100%;
}

